# SVG saved from Illustrator loses the transparency around the image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

Ive used Image Trace to convert a PNG to vectors in Illustrator. By changing the colour of my artboard I can see the transparency around the image is there.

When I save the image as an SVG it looses this transparency. The area around the image is solid white. How can I preserve this transparency?

Comment: What are you using to view the saved SVG? Are you using it in a web page? If so, can you share the code? It might be a coding issue. You could use Codepen (http://codepen.io/) or JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) to share an example of the code here.

Comment: Did you expand and delete all of the white space after tracing the image?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a layer, or shape underneath.
Paste the SVG code here if you want a detailed answer.